# How to set up a web e-payment system(Donation System )?

Tags: php, html, database, payment

The current website is running only with HTML pages.

My idea to set up a web epayment system (Donation System) is that I would like to build a web server with Xmapp. I am going to build a db stored the payment info . The HTML form passes the info to the db and the field of payment amount passes to the payment website . After the user clicks the submit button , it redirects to the epayment websites .The users end the process with the epayment websites. And it auto-generate an email to the user.

Is this idea possible ?

## Update

1.Any more convenient ways to set up the db with purely HTML?

2.Should I register the shop ac in the epayment websites ?

Comment: sure its possible, time to start writing code.

Comment: @smith please see update

Comment: No you can't set up a db purely with html. HTML is simply descriptive. It *does* nothing. The web browser takes the HTML, CSS and Javascript and displays you a web page. To interact with a database you will need some form of **server-side** scripting language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Smith is still right but it looks like you are going to have to implement a basic CRUD application with php, you 'cannot' implement this without a programming language ( i.e. with only html). 
HERE IS A SIMPLE TUTORIAL: 
https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/php-crud-tutorial-part-1
There are apis for payment integration with php.